# Create Heatmap in R for 3 variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have a CSV file with 3 variables (Job Time - V1, Job Size - V2 and Wait time - V3). Although there might not be an entry for Every pair of (V1 vs V2). How do I create a heatmap like the one attached (although I'd prefer R, any other language or framework works as well)?

My data looks like this (Has 3 million entries): V1, V3 - seconds, V2 - number

```
V1      V2    V3
1135    10    9
1071    10    7
4502    12    591
1087    10    7
1948    12    9
3445    16    8
9521    16    8
9115    16    9
30525   16    8
29522   16    10
```

[HeatMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sp4O.png)

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
library(tidyverse)

d %>%
  ggplot(aes(V1, V2)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = V3))
```

Some docs for [geom_raster](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_tile.html).

Comment: I think you interchanged the variables V3,V2 for my graph, but Thanks a lot for the link and answer. It helped me move in the right direction